# Android Marshmallow: Revoking Permissions and UI testing

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, ui-testing, runtime-permissions

When revoking a permission (e.g: Locations) from an App in Android Marshmallow, the app process is terminated. Is there any way to handle this for UI tests that wants to test different cases (permissions enabled/disabled)? Attempting to use UIAutomator to set the permissions in App Setting results in a crash since the app terminates right after permission is revoked. Appreciate any insight/comments!

Comment: Why on earth can Android not issue a callback to allow the app to stop the location process. background app termination can be a real pain for some apps, especially as the user will not know that the app has terminated.